# How do I resize .swipeAction modifier buttons?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this list of items that have a `.swipeAction` modifier attached to them. I would like to be able to replace these with something that actually fits the height of the dark blue portion. Alternatively, I could add "True" spacing between each cell, however any attempts I've made to do that have resulted in white bars all over the place or the cell's view is messed up. As you can tell from this screenshot, it is not aligned properly and the only way I can see to fix it is to implement my own custom `.swipeAction` however I'm trying to avoid that.

[image]

#### Swipe Action

```
List {
    ForEach (vm.events) { event in
        CountdownView(dueDate: event)
            .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                Button (action: {
                    vm.deleteEvent(event: event)
                }) { Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.circle.fill") }
                .tint(.red)
                
                Button (action: {
                    vm.deleteEvent(event: event)
                }) { Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil.circle.fill") }
                .tint(.promptlyTeal)
            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .background(Color.promptlyLightNavy)
    }
}
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
.background(Color.promptlyLightNavy)
```

My attempts have been to add padding to the cell itself, which you see here, but that causes the swipe action buttons to not appear. Other attempts have been to change the `listViewStyle` to some other type, but that hasn't proven fruitful. How can I get the space between cells, or resize the `.swipeAction`?

Comment: Theoretically they should respect say `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(..., bottom: 20,...`, but seems there is a bug.

Comment: Please provide a reproducable example. Especially what is CountdownView. Your problem is most likely in that View.